# Writing 1 = 10^0 with \num{e0}

Tags: siunitx

Why does `\num{e0}` automatically translate to `1` instead of `10^0`?

And how is this fixed in case you want to alter the default behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `retain-zero-exponent=true`, which by default is `false`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{retain-zero-exponent=true}
\begin{document}
\num{e0}
\end{document}
```